# dompdf render html codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, dompdf

i wanna render html page (using dompdf in CI) like this

[image: html image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6apgR.png)[first image]
but when i gererated, output to be
   [image: pdf render](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TNiHl.png)[second image]
before i edited, generating error [error issue](https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/issues/758) so i edited stylesheet.cls.php, but output as 2nd    image...any idea...thanx

Comment: can you write the image src?

Comment: all image src work fine, except orange backgroud image that accross by 3 images

Comment: actually dompdf only accept directory location instead of url

Comment: yup...that was i'm thinking....but why orange background image cannot render like a html page (1st image)..any suggestion

Comment: It's difficult to answer the questions without knowing which dompdf version you're using as well as seeing your code. FYI, versions prior to 0.6.0 only handled binary transparency and did not handle opacity.